# OpenCV Java - dnn::net forward resolution mismatch

Tags: opencv, resolution, torch, forward

I trained a CNN model by using Torch (Lua) and then loaded it on OpenCV Java. The model was structured to get `112*112` as an input image. However I accidentally put `128*128` to the model.

I expected an error, but the model just ran smoothly and made some results. Why is it? Does OpenCV just ignore surplus parts of the input?

Below is a part of my code:

```
Mat bgrImage = bgrImages.get(i);
Mat inputBlob = Dnn.blobFromImage(bgrImage);
objectNet.setInput(inputBlob);
Mat fwdResultMat = objectNet.forward();
```

Comment: JSong, it depends of the model. Isn't it? If it has size-specific layers like fully-connected or reshape (or view like it names at Torch) we'll face a problem of how to multiply vector of size `1x128` on the matrix of size `112x10`, in example. However there are different models that are size-independent (accuracy may be different correspondingly) like image segmentation or object detection. BTW, Have you tried to pass `128x128` input into an origin Torch framework?

Comment: @DmitryKurtaev Hi, thanks for your comment. I tried passing `128x128` to my network. The result was a batch of results. The expected output for the input `112x112` is `1024`. When I put `128x128`, then the result was something like `5x1024`. (I don't remember the exact number.) I tested this on Lua Torch, so not sure about OpenCV.